# Iterating over JSON returned by a Service on angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-resource

I am trying to iterate over and search by id and return the other values corresponding to the id from a JSON object of the type shown below, by $resource in the controller. I am not understanding where am I wrong in this case? Please help!

This is the controller

```
appSettings.controller('applistController', ['$scope', 'AppListService',
    function($scope, AppListService){
    // Have to iterate here to search for an id, how?
    // The Above app.json file is returned by the ApplistService(not showing the factory here as it works already.)
        $scope.allapps = AppListService.listAllApps().get();
    // console.log($scope.allapps.data) returns undefined as so does console.log($scope.allapps.length).
    // Where am I wrong?
    }
]);
```

The JSON is of the type :

```
{"data":[
    {
      "id":"files_trashbin",
      "name": "TrashBin",
      "licence":"AGPL",
      "require":"4.9",
      "shipped": "true",
      "active":true
    },
    {
      "id":"files_external",
      "name": "External Storage",
      "licence":"AGPL",
      "require":"4.93",
      "shipped":"true",
      "active":true
    }
    ],
  "status":"success"
}
```

Comment: Firstly your json is incorrect after `"active":true` comma is unnecessary and you should send also AppListService to better understand your problem.

Comment: @lukpaw I just fixed the JSON to make it valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AppListService.listAllApps().get();` returns promise i suppose. Sounds like you try to print before got actual data.

I would use following approach:

```
var appSettings = angular.module('myModule', ['ngResource']);

appSettings.controller('applistController', ['$scope', 'AppListService',
function($scope, AppListService){

     AppListService.listAllApps()
                        .then(function (result) {
                           $scope.allapp = result;                           
                        }, function (result) {
                            alert("Error: No data returned");
                        });  

}]);


appSettings.factory('AppListService', ['$resource','$q',  function($resource, $q) {

  var data = $resource('somepath', 
         {},
        { query: {method:'GET', params:{}}}
                 );


       var factory = {

            listAllApps: function () {
              var deferred = $q.defer();
              deferred.resolve(data);
             return deferred.promise;
            }

        }
        return factory;
}]);
```

Comment: Don't know how I missed that. thanks a lot Maxim! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is code that shows the extraction of the id values, based on your json.

```
var json = '{"data":[{"id":"files_trashbin","name":"TrashBin","licence":"AGPL","require":"4.9","shipped":"true","active":true},{"id":"files_external","name":"External Storage","licence":"AGPL","require":"4.93","shipped":"true","active":true}],"status":"success"}';
$scope.allapps = JSON.parse(json);
$scope.ids = new Array();
var sourceData = $scope.allapps["data"];
for (var i=0; i<sourceData.length; i++) {
    $scope.ids.push(sourceData[i].id);
}
```

Here is a jsFiddle giving [an example of this extraction](http://jsfiddle.net/yaakov/YLBEt/), integrated with Angular.

This code assumes that the JSON returned by your service is identical to what you have shown. Please note - there were initially some extra and missing commas in your JSON text (which I subsequently fixed), which may have also contributed to the errors that you were seeing.